# Checking datagridview checkbox from code doesn't check it on UI

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm loading a list of databases from my app.config, and I want to check my datagridview checkboxes on these databases. When I debug the method it assigns a true value, but it doesn't change on UI and the value of checkbox is still false.

The method runs before showing my Windows Forms, after InitializeComponent(). If I click on the button, that calls the same Method after Windows Forms is loaded it works as a charm. Not automatically though.
I'm doing this because I want to recreate my datagridview with all checks every time I launch the application, and it's been really bugging me. I tried refreshing and updating dataGridView, commiting updates, ending updates before I assign a value, I also tried setting property "TrueValue" on checkbox column to true, but it didn't help.

```
private void CheckDatabasesFromConfig()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < SQLDatabases.RowCount; i++)
            {
                if (listOfDatabasesToBackup.Contains(SQLDatabases.Rows[i].Cells["Database Name"].Value))
                {
                    SQLDatabases.Rows[i].Cells["Backup"].Value = true;
                }

            }
        }
```

I want to open the application and see checkboxes checked according to this list on my datagridview, without clicking anything.

Comment: I am unable to test anything at the moment.  But, if you are calling `CheckDatabasesFromConfig` in your Form constructor, then try calling it from `Form.Load` event handler instead and let us know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

"Database Name" in Cells["Database Name"] is not a valid identifier so "if" expression is always false.
correct your column name defined in dataGridView.

Comment: I deleted the spaces, making it a DatabaseName but it still didn't work. I tested the code during debugging and if statement is in fact true, so it works, and it assigns a value. Any ideas?

Comment: restart VS or run in release mode may solve your problem. if no, all codes must be reviewed

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem - I'm sorry for misinformation. I had the datagridview in second page of the tabcontrol, and since I didn't open it, the controls didn't load. 
It helped to perform a simple tabPage2.show() before calling my method.